# How can I use child variables instead of parent variables in Java?

Tags: java

```
class Parent {
    public String name = "parent";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public String name = "child";
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();
        System.out.println(parent.getName());
        System.out.println(child.getName());
    }
}
```

The output is

```
parent
parent

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have this code.
And I can't get why **getName()** for Child returns Parent's name.
I'm expecting that **getName()** fot Child will return "child", but that's not happening.

Could you help me with questions where am I wrong and how to fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: remove the public String name = "child", and just add a constructor that sets the value of the already existing variable called name

Answer (score 0):

Because when you re-declare a field like `name`, you create a new one, not change the existing one.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() { name = "child"; }
}
```

In other words, in your example you have two fields, not one.  `Parent.name` and `Child.name` and `getName()` returns the first one.  That's what's causing the problem.